# Puppet installing multiple packages results in Package[undef] error

Tags: puppet

I am receiving the following error on a Puppet agent when trying to install multiple packages at once:

`err: /Stage[main]/Template::Infrastructure/Package[undef]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install undef' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do`

The code generating the error is:

```
$packages = [ 'qemu-kvm', 'qemu-kvm-tools', 'drbd84-tools', 'kmod-drbd84' ]
package {
  $::packages :
    ensure  =>  'installed',
    require =>  Class['yumrepos::elrepo']
}
```

The problem is intermittent. Is there a better way to install multiple packages at once without having to setup a package resource for each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using it as `$::packages` states explicitly that you want the variable to be looked up in the top scope, outside of any class.  Since you seem to be defining it inside a class, this won't work.

Just use `package { $packages:` or `package { $classname::packages:` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I had not quite a grasp on the difference of first looking in top scope. The way the variable is used makes much more sense to me now.